# Отваливается ViewBinding

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-view-binding

Причина неизвестна. Просто спустя какое-то время он отваливается. Не добавляю никаких новых плагинов и тд. Он просто начинает рекомендовать мне создать класс ActivityBinding и светиться красным. При этом Приложение запускается. Помогает если переставить значение viewBinding с true на false и обратно в файле build.gradle, но временно.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'realm-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}



android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.androidapp.diaryapp"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
    realm {
        syncEnabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-native:0.9.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.8.11.1'
    implementation 'com.applandeo:material-calendar-view:1.7.0'
}
```

gradle(Project):

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.21"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.3.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Тоже иногда сталкиваюсь с таким поведением, не знаю почему но мне помогает Clean а затем Rebuild

Answer (score 1):

Это обычно происходит при использовании "Apply Chenges and Restart Activity"

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос